# sed: truncate long entry across multiple lines

Tags: regex, sed

First, I have what I believe to be a workable solution. However, test cases
are one thing ...reality is not always so kind. This is a "Does this look right?"
question ...or, better, "Where might this fail? Suggest improvements?" question.

**Problem:**

Title should not creep past one line.

Test file:

```
You have a hold available for pickup as of 2012-01-13:
Title: Really Long Test Title Regarding Random Gibberish. Volume 1, A-B, United States
 and affiliated territories, United Nations, countries of the world
Author: Barrel Roll Morton
Copy: 3
#end-of-record
You have a hold available for pickup as of 2012-01-13:
Title: Short Catalogue of Random Gibberish. Volume 1, A-B, United States
Author: Skippy Credenza
Copy: 12
#end-of-record
```

Expected output:

```
You have a hold available for pickup as of 2012-01-13:
Title: Really Long Test Title Regarding Random Gibberish. Volume 1, A-B, United States
Author: Barrel Roll Morton
Copy: 3
#end-of-record
You have a hold available for pickup as of 2012-01-13:
Title: Short Catalogue of Random Gibberish. Volume 1, A-B, United States
Author: Skippy Credenza
Copy: 12
#end-of-record
```

My solution:

```
sed -e '/^Title/{N;/\nAuthor:/!{s/\n.*$//}}' test-file.txt
```

My logic re: above proposed solution

- Look for regex /^Title/
- Grab next line
- If next line does *not* match /^Author/
- Then search for regex /\n.*$/
- Replace with nada.

Is there a more bullet proof way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks good, but if you don't have control on how long that first line of text is, you can further truncate it using something like

```
sed '/^Title/{N;/\nAuthor:/!{s/^\(....................\).*\n.*$/\1/;};}' test-file.txt
```

(You don't need the -e, but it doesn't hurt either).

I use an old-school sed, so I need the `;};}` extra-bits.

Adjust the number of '.'s in the match-pattern for the length of value you want to capture.

Newer sed support curly-braced ranges, something like, cut I don't have access to confirm.

```
sed '/^Title/{N;/\nAuthor:/!{s/^\(.\{30,50\}\).*\n.*$/\1/;};}' test-file.txt
```

**Edit** per @JonathanLeffler 's comment below. fixed range notation, change 30,50 to values that work for you.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your version offers the advantage of controlling length of title string. However, the /.*$/ part seems a bit "loose" to me. I suppose it takes in to account blank lines and is safe after all?

Comment: you only get 1 line of extra input when you do 'N', right? If it's really important, I'd query my data source and see what corner cases existing currently in the data, and then write thee sed to fix that. ELSE, it is possible to loop in sed to keep doing 'N' until you find Author, but it's no longer a one liner ;-) Good luck.

Comment: Hmm.. one other thing, I think that if you have have a line that is shorter than the length of the `.....` char match pattern, that may be a problem. If you're checking your data for corner cases, be sure to print out the length for shortest. Not certain at this point what I would do to fix that case. Let me know if you need help with it. Good luck.

Comment: Even fairly old versions of `sed` support `\{lo,hi\}` range notations. However, 'fairly old' does not extend as far back as 7th Edition UNIX in 1978.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/^Title/,/^Author/{//!d}' file
```

If you wish to truncate the `Title` line, then

```
sed '/^Title/,/^Author/{//!d;s/^\(Title.\{25\}\).*/\1/}' file
```

This reduces the `Title` to 30 characters in length.

Comment: This was a fun one to decipher. re: {//!d} - sed auto-substitutes the last match in blank match slashes, correct? So // translates to /^Author/? Nice.

Comment: What if the title is less than 30 chars?

Comment: Also, in your first example ( works as expected BTW ), I see that it uses a regex range ...but why doesn't it delete the /^Title/?

Comment: @Bubnoff it deletes *niether* `Title` or `Author` only the lines inbetween. A substitution command must match *first* before it can replace, if there are not 30 characters in the `Title` it'll do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Although not exactly what you asked for (potong's solution seems the best for that), the following will append an N-line title into a single line rather than truncate it.

```
sed '/^Title:/{:a;N;/\nAuthor:/!s/\n//;ta;P;D}' test-file.txt
```

#### Output

```
$ sed '/^Title:/{:a;N;/\nAuthor:/!s/\n//;ta;P;D}' test-file.txt
You have a hold available for pickup as of 2012-01-13:
Title: Really Long Test Title Regarding Random Gibberish. Volume 1, A-B, United States and affiliated territories, United Nations, countries of the world.  Also, this title is a whole three lines in length
Author: Barrel Roll Morton
Copy: 3
#end-of-record
You have a hold available for pickup as of 2012-01-13:
Title: Short Catalogue of Random Gibberish. Volume 1, A-B, United States
Author: Skippy Credenza
Copy: 12
#end-of-record
```

Comment: though not applicable to this particular problem -- I can still use it on the next batch of messes. Will up-vote. Thanks!

Comment: By 'not applicable', I only meant that the constraints of the current template require a single line less than 70 or 80 chars. I plan to update the template --

Comment: @Bubnoff Thanks. Check out the updated answer. It can now handle arbitrary long titles.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with `awk` then you can do something like this -

```
awk '/Title:/{print $0; getline; while ($0!~/Author:/) {getline}}1' file
```

Comment: You might try `/^Author/{p=0};!p;/^Title/{p=1}' file`